# Using DATEDIFF within a SELECT

Tags: sql, datediff

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Test,
    FIRST_VALUE (CONVERT(DATE, datetime)) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) StartDate,
    LAST_VALUE  (CONVERT(DATE, datetime)) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) EndDate,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, EndDate)
FROM
    Tests
```

Any ideas on how I can include the difference between the 2 dates within the SELECT?

I want to be able to use the values StartDate and EndDate however I'm getting an error saying StartDate and EndDate are invalid columns.

Comment: If the values are in order, why not use `min()` and `max()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use aliases you created in the `SELECT` clause elsewhere in the same `SELECT` clause, so you need to place your `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` functions within the `DATEDIFF()` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Test,
    FIRST_VALUE (CONVERT(DATE, datetime)) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) StartDate,
    LAST_VALUE  (CONVERT(DATE, datetime)) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) EndDate,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, FIRST_VALUE (CONVERT(DATE, datetime)) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC)
                  , LAST_VALUE  (CONVERT(DATE, datetime)) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) )
FROM
    Tests
```

Or you could run everything but the `DATEDIFF()` in a subquery/cte:

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, EndDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
        Test,
        FIRST_VALUE (CONVERT(DATE, datetime)) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) StartDate,
        LAST_VALUE  (CONVERT(DATE, datetime)) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) EndDate
      FROM
        Tests
      ) AS sub
```

You also can't use aliases created in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause, but you can use them in `ORDER BY` and of course in any outer queries.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, I think your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT Test,
       CONVERT(DATE, MIN(datetime)) as StartDate,
       CONVERT(DATE, MAX(datetime) as EndDate,
       DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, MIN(datetime)), CONVERT(DATE, MAX(datetime)))
FROM Tests
GROUP BY Test;
```

The functions `MIN()` and `MAX()` are more succinct.  In addition, the query is easier to read as a `group by` rather than as a `select distinct`.